# Sum of series of $\cot^{-1}\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}+ \cot^{-1}\frac{9}{\sqrt{3}}+ \cot^{-1}\frac{15}{\sqrt{3}}+\cot^{-1}\frac{23}{\sqrt{3}}+...$

Tags: trigonometry

Sum of series of  $\cot^{-1}\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}+ \cot^{-1}\frac{9}{\sqrt{3}}+ \cot^{-1}\frac{15}{\sqrt{3}}+\cot^{-1}\frac{23}{\sqrt{3}}+...$ is equal to ….

I found the $n^{th}$ term as $\cot^{-1}\frac{n^2+n+3}{\sqrt{3}}$ but not able to break it up further to be telescopic function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1+\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt3}\cdot \dfrac n{\sqrt3}}{\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt3}-\dfrac n{\sqrt3}}=?$$

$$\cot (A-B)=?$$

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series